# reversing a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, reverse

```
#include <stdio.h>
void reverse(int len, char s[], char b[]);

int main() {
    char s[5] = "hello";
    char b[5];
    reverse(5, s, b);
    return 0;
}

void reverse(int len, char s[], char b[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        b[(len - 1) - i] = s[i];
    }
    printf("%s : %s\n", s, b);
    printf("%s", b);
}
```

Here is my code above in `C`. When I run it, it switches the string `s[]` to `b[]` but `b[]`also includes `s[]`. Can someone please thoroughly explain what I'm doing wrong? I really appreciate it.

Comment: nit-pik: `size_t len` would make more sense than `int len`, seeing as a string can't have a negative length

Comment: Your program should throw an error.

Answer (score 8):

```
char s[5] = "hello";
```

This is wrong, you need one more `[6]` in order to store the trailing `'\0'` (same for `b`)

It's better to omit the array size:

```
char s[] = "hello";
char b[sizeof(s)];
```

And you need `b[i] = '\0';` after the `for` loop.

Comment: why is it 6 instead of 5? h e l l o is 4 letters, plus a \0 for the 5th element? or am i missing something? Thanks a lot
-Edit: thanks i got it!

Comment: @slee0743 Write a function that takes "hello" as an argument and prints its' length

Comment: Hello is `5` letters , count again ;)

Comment: Maybe if the last 'o' is a silent vowel.

Answer (score 3):

Your string buffers are too small, they must be six characters or more to hold the string `"hello"`. Remember that strings C have a terminating `'\0'`-character at the end; that won't fit with space for only five characters.

Also, when reversing you never copy the terminating character.

You need `b[len - 1] = '\0';` before exiting `reverse()`.

When you pass non-terminated strings to `printf()`'s `"%s`" format, you get undefined behavior. Typically it "runs off the end" of the string, printing whatever it happens to find in memory, until it finds a character with the value 0 which causes it to stop.

Comment: why does b[ ] end up having 10 elements when i made b to be only 5? thanks a lot by the way!

Comment: @slee0743: "*That*, Detective, is the right question. (Program terminated.)" The problem with this is that since you only *reserved* space for 5 characters (`char b[5];`), you cannot safely fit 6 characters in it -- and also not 10! That means that *whatever* result you get, it is *undefined* behavior. It may work, it may crash, it may answer "42".

Answer (score 0):

The %s format specifier expects a string: An array of characters ending in a nul byte. You are not supplying that, so you are getting rubbish results. To hold a *string* with five characters, you need at least six chars.

Answer (score 0):

every string in c is terminated by `\0` which is a null character. so the array size should be enough to hold the string along with null character.
I will suggests to increase the size of array.

```
important :-
```

at the last assign b[last_index]='\0'; 
so that string b can be terminated by \0. otherwise it might give garbage values along with actual data while printing the string b.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you just need to include

```
#include<string.h>
```

and use

```
strrev(a);
```

where a is the character array or string.

Whereas, your code can be modified too, to be written like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
void reverse(int len, char s[], char b[]);

int main() {
    char s[5] = "hello";
    char b[5];
    reverse(5, s, b);
    return 0;
}

void reverse(int len, char s[], char b[]) {
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0,j=len-1; i <=j; i++, j--) {
        b[j]=a[i];
    }
    printf("%s : %s\n", s, b);
    printf("%s", b);
}
```